# Rails 4 - Automatically fill in IP address location on the locations input field using Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have this form:

```
= simple_form_for @post, validate: true do |f| 
            .edit-form
                = f.input :title
                = f.input :location
                = f.input :price
                = f.button :submit
```

The input form obviously is a blank text box that people put in their location.

[image]

I currently have Geocoder in my app and what I would like to do is pre-fill the location text box with the location of the user. Doing this requires this line of code:

```
= request.location.city
= request.location.state
```

I want to prefill this in my location text box. I tried doing something like this:

```
= f.input :location, value: (#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state})
```

The end product should have the info filled in automatically and look like this:

[image]

This did not work. How do I insert it to accomplish this goal?

---

Comment: you are close, do `value: "#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}"`..

Comment: For some reason that did not work when I tried = f.input :location, value: "Just a test" just to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are wrong. The correct way to do this is:

```
= f.input :location, input_html: { value: "#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}"}
```

It is necessary to include the

```
input_html: { }
```

If you want to add any additional HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting parenthesis around the value, use quotes to make it `value: "#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}"`.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work. I tried this = f.input :location, value: "Just a test" to see if Just a test is prefilled. It didn't